# Code review - if else function

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I cannot for the life of me understand why I am getting the error:

"Type error: eCurVar is undefined". Please review the code below.

```
    var aBBTemplates = document.getElementsByClassName ("cBBTemplates");
    var i = 2;
    while (i < aBBTemplates.length)
    {
        var eCurVar = aBBTemplates[i];
        if (eCurVar === e.target)
        {
            eCurVar.style.zIndex = 3;
     // type error: eCurVar is undefined on the following line. 
        }   else if (eCurVar.style.zIndex === 3)    {
            console.log (eCurVar);
            eCurVar.style.zIndex = 3-1;
        }   else
        {
            console.log (eCurVar)
            eCurVar.style.zIndex = i;
        }
        i--;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After each iteration `i` is decremented of one unit... and after three iterations it becomes negative; so you read `aBBTemplates[-1]` you get `undefined`.

When you can't understand what's going on with few `console.log`s, your best bet is to add a `debugger;` instruction, and open your devtool (usually by pressing F12).

As for your problem you could fix it by adding a check on `i`:

```
while (i < aBBTemplates.length && i >= 0) {
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that made perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

In the second case `aBBTemplates[i]` probably returns `null`

Comment: Are you implying that getElementsByClassName returns an array containing null ?

Comment: I'm implying that `aBBTemplates[i]`, i.e. the item of the array at index `i`, evaluates to `null`.

Comment: @dystroy If you read OP's code, you'll see that he's * decrementing* `i` and at some point it will be `-1`. And `aBBTemplates[-1]` probably will be `null`. Thanks for the downvote anyway.

Comment: I've read that, that's why I upvoted bru's answer, that is the first answer to bring something more than just repeating the error message. Seriously, I would have suggested to comment instead of answering if you had said more than that...

Answer (score 1):

You start with `i` equal to 2. Lets assume that `aBBTemplates[2]` returns something meaningful. You do someting with it and them *decrement* `i`. Lets assume `aBBTemplates[1]` in meaningful.

Keep going, and sooner or lates `i` becomes -1, which will definately not be meaningful when reading `aBBTemplates[-1]`

Answer (score 1):

Into if function check if also eCurrVar is not a null

```
if (eCurVar != null && eCurVar === e.target){
// your code
} else {
// if ecurvar == null or ecurvar != e.targer
}
```

Also in while check if your `i` is possitive number, because array do not contains items with negative indexes:

```
while(i >= 0 && i < aBBTemplates.length)
```